# Making cvs file of facebook friends with python to import in new profile

Tags: python, facebook, csv

I'm making a new facebook profile, just want to start fresh without having to go through everything and untagging, deleting, etc... I would however like to keep my contacts.
I have a list of all contacts in a .txt file since facebook provides the list if you ask for it. The idea is to put all names into a `csv` file for gmail and then import the gmail contacts into the new facebook profile

It's in this format, however there are over 700 names:

```
Sander Krabbendam
Jonatan Silva (jonasilv@gmail.com)
Jesus A. Peñaloza
Tim Travell
```

I wrote a program that separates first names from the rest and removes emails if there are also email as in Jonatan's name above:

```
check = open('names.txt')
lsNames = list()
lsLastnames = list()

for line in check:
    line = line.strip() #.decode('string_escape')
    word = line.split()
    lsNames.append(word[0])
    lsLastnames.append(word[1:])
    for lastname in lsLastnames:
        for str in lastname:
            for char in str:
                if char == '@': 
                    lastname.pop()
```

So lsNames has the 1st name and lsLastnames has the rest without email. 
I need to know how to pass that into a csv format that gmail accepts:
[image: gmail csv format for contacts]

The problem is also that some names have very strange decoding since I opened the file (this are the names above now in the lsLastnames, Peñaloza is now `Pe\xc3\xb1aloza`:

```
['Krabbendam']
['Silva']
['A.', 'Pe\xc3\xb1aloza']
['Travell']
```

What I need is to put the names and last names with the latin characters in the Corresponding A and B columns of a excel style form. 
Please help! my knowledge of python is still very limited!

Comment: What about column C..are you also generating it from your code...or you don't need it?...only A & B.. ?

Comment: Gmail just need this format to put all the names in a list of contacts and then if column c was there it would just add the email to each person, but since i just want to use for importing all the names into facebook, so I don't think its really necessary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
import csv
import sys

with open('myContactList.csv', 'wt') as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        writer.writerow( ('First Name', 'Last Name') )
        for a, b in zip(lsNames, lsLastnames):
            writer.writerow( (a, ' '.join(map(lambda s:s.decode('utf-8'),b)))
```

I used `join` on the second row as you showed a case where last name could have two strings:

`'A.'` `'Peñaloza'`.

And then applying the `utf-8` decoding to get the correct `unicode` characters, for example:

```
>>> l = ['A.', 'Pe\xc3\xb1aloza']
>>> ''.join(map(lambda s:s.decode('utf-8'), l))
u'A.Pe\xf1aloza'
>>> print ''.join(map(lambda s:s.decode('utf-8'), l))
A.Peñaloza
```

**EDIT: As improvement to your code**

```
with open('names.txt', 'r') as check:
    lsNames = list()
    lsLastnames = list()

    for line in check:
        word = line.rstrip().split()
        for item in word[::-1]: #start looking from last item for quick search
            if '@' in item:
                word.remove(item)
        lsNames.append(word[0])
        if len(word[1:]) > 1: #Last Name with two strings
            lsLastnames.append(' '.join(word[1:]))
        else:
            lsLastnames.append(word[1])

with open('myContactList.csv', 'wt') as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        writer.writerow( ('First Name', 'Last Name') )
        for a, b in zip(lsNames, lsLastnames):
            writer.writerow((a.decode('utf-8'), b.decode('utf-8')))
```

Comment: Amazing! In preview it looks perfect even the encoding! where was the encoding fixed!? Just one thing though when opening in excel everything seems to be writen in the A column. I will try uploading to gmail tomorrow because it's very late in my timezone. Thank you very much Iron Fist, already big improvement for my quest :)

Comment: @Bizzare .. No pblm ... If you are happy with my answer, consider accepting it

Comment: done! will try it now. just one thing, would you recomend a way I could clean up my code to remove the email strings if there are from lsLastnames? instead of my 3 nested for loops? maybe list comprehension or re?

Comment: Thanks a bunch you've been really helpful! I wish I could double upvote!

Comment: @Bizarre .. No pblm...that is fine...you already did your part.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to store your string in `UTF-8 encoding`.

Comment: how do I do that? I tried with .decode('utf-8'), and .decode('string_escape') but with both it still looks very strange

Comment: @Bizarre - `.decode('utf-8')` should do it. Check out Iron Fist's updated answer.